# Freeing allocated memory of VM in VM Ware Workstation Player

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I had Ubuntu 14.04 on VM Ware Workstation Player in Windows platform.I had allocated 150 GB to it.When I wanted to delete that VM ,I had removed it from library,but I think it has not released all memory acquired by VM .So my query is, does removing VM from library also frees up memory that were allocated to it?If not then how can I add it again to VMPlayer so that I can delete it from disk.
I tried to find VM files in virtual machine folder to access it again in player , but its not present there.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @nik did you find the solution for this?